# To store an int value in a Byte arraylist

Tags: java

How can i store an integer value in a Byte ArrayList.

```
class sample
{

int a=4;

ArrayList<Byte> arr=new ArrayList<Byte>();

// I dont want to type cast 'a' to a byte.
// Is there any other way - like if i can get 4bytes of memory and allocate the int into this //ArrayList-is it possible here?
}
```

Comment: So you want the `int` to be split into 4 bytes?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Yes!! How can i have the first 4 bytes of the arraylist<Byte> and add the integer to it?

Comment: Don't use an ArrayList to store Bytes. It is not only really inefficient, the stanard APIs don't support it.  Can you explain why you are trying to do this as there is many alternatives e.g. if you need Little Endian you need to use a ByteBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

As @PeterLawrey already mentioned you could use a `ByteBuffer` for something like that, consider the following example:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;


public class BytebufferTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    bb.putInt(1);
    bb.flip();
    while (bb.hasRemaining()) {
      System.out.println("[" + bb.get() + "]");
    }
  }
}
```

Will give you the following output:

```
[0]
[0]
[0]
[1]
```

With the `hasRemaining()` function you can iterate over the `ByteBuffer`.

It would be helpful if you give us some more detail about what exactly you want to do, so we don't have to guess around(as i just did).

Comment: I am working on building a compiler.I am trying to build an array of instruction sets.Basically i am working on register level implementation now.So i have an instruction set stack of type byte and i have to parse the code example:-9+8; where i have to store opcode/9,opcode/8,add in the stack(byte).